# How to position an image on the title page?

Tags: titles, includegraphics

I'm trying to make a template for my university course which involves putting the logo of my course of study on the title page. I figured out how to include the picture on the title page, but I need the picture to be on top of the page. I'm aware that I can position an image with `[t]` on top of the page, but only in the `figure` environment. This is what I have so far:

```
\author{John Doe et al.}
\title{\centering\includegraphics[width=6cm]{image} CoSci 101}
\date{xx.xx.xxxx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

I need the picture on the top of the page and the title below it.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using for this template you're creating?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest here would be to place the image after your page has been constructed. This is possible via [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) using something like `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*`, which `Add`s a `Picture` (anything really) `To` the `F`ore`G`round of the current page (`*`) that will be `Ship`ped `out`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}

\author{John Doe et al.}
\title{CoSci 101}
\date{xx.xx.xxxx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add picture to ForeGround of current page only
  \AtPageUpperLeft{% Placement starts at upper-left corner of page
    \hspace*{0.5\paperwidth}% Move to middle of page
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-2\baselineskip}{% Lower image into position
      \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}}}}}% Set image

Something else.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the "\centering" before \includegraphics and replace it with   \vspace*{ycm} and \hspace*{xcm} to add vertical and horizontal spacing in a direction (negative cm values also possible). Also the name of the image in the folder and the filetype is in the {} after includegraphics. So if the name of your image is CoSci101 and its a png for example, then the code would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{John Doe et al.}
\title{ \vspace*{-3cm}  \hspace*{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{CoSci101.png}}
\date{xx.xx.xxxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

dfgdf
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solves your problem.

the image you choose must be saved in the same folder as the .tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{John Doe et al.}
\title{\centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} CoSci 101}
\date{xx.xx.xxxx}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

dfgdf
\end{document}
```